# Django -> acceso al diccionario retornado por una funcion context_proccesor

Tags: django

Desde un template quiero acceder al diccionario para obtener la clave y su valor y crear ademas un href.

```
from .models import MdPaginas

def fn_mdpaginas(request):
    mdpaginas = dict()
    paginas = MdPaginas.objects.all()
    for pagina in paginas:
        mdpaginas[pagina.title] = pagina.id
    print('procesador de paginas ->', mdpaginas)
    return mdpaginas
```

El print se ejecuta y se muestra en consola 3 elementos en el diccionario.
Sin embargo este template código no funciona:

```
{% for id, titulo in mdpaginas.items  %}
   <p>
     {{titulo}} hola
   </p>
{% empty %}
   No hay paginas  
{% endfor %}
```

EN HTML solo aparece 'No hay paginas'

¿ Dónde está mi error ?
¿ Cómo se puede hacer ?

Comment: porque no pasas directamente "paginas " como context a tu template.. y lo haces con un ciclo for: {% for item in paginas  %} <p>{{ item.title }}<p>..{% endfor %}

Answer (score 1):

Saludos podrías realizar algo así:

```
from .models import MdPaginas

def fn_mdpaginas(request):
    paginas = MdPaginas.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'mi_template.html', {'paginas':paginas})
```

en tu **template**:

```
{% for pagina in paginas %}
<p>{{ pagina.title }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Espero te sirva..!!